# How can ImageView link to web page?

Tags: android

is it possible to make an imageview link to a web page such that when user taps on the image, it takes them to a web page?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Just add a click listener to the image to open an URL:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foo_bar);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://casidiablo.net"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: `startActivity()` starts a new activity. The issue I am having is when I press when the "Complete action using" pops up and I press back, my app just closes, without just closing the "Complete action using" popup

Answer (score 0):

That's truly possible, at onClick handler you need to start an activity with intent specifying the uri. See [How to open default browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505788/how-to-open-default-browser/3505804#3505804) for example.

Answer (score 0):

another method we can even use is

```
    image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

Intent redirect2=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RedirectAct.class);
startActivity(redirect2);

    }
});
```