# Add web link to ImageView?

Tags: android, url, imageview

is it possible (and how) to make an ImageView link to web page such that when users clicks on image, it takes them to a web page? I've made this structure and i need web link for every ImageView:

```
<ScrollView
 <LinearLayout     
  <ImageView1
  <ImageView2
  <ImageView3
    .  
    . 
    .
 </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 10):

You only need one `onClick` event to handle all `ImageView` clicks.

Use `android:tag` attribute to assign the url that you want to open.
Use `android:onClick`attribute to assign the method that handle the click event.

**In xml:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yourimage1" 
    android:tag="http://site_1.com"
    android:onClick="openBrowser"/>  

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/yourimage2" 
    android:tag="http://site_2.com"
    android:onClick="openBrowser"/>
```

**In activity:**

```
public void openBrowser(View view){

    //Get url from tag
    String url = (String)view.getTag();

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);

    //pass the url to intent data
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically add a click listener and when the image is pressed go to the web page with an intent.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foo_bar);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://casidiablo.net"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**Original source:** [How can ImageView link to web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536165/how-can-imageview-link-to-web-page)

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest way is to use an `ImageButton`. In the onClick method of the ImageButton, send an Intent with the url to either open a browser or your own WebView. If you don't want it to look a button, just set the onClickListener on the `ImageView`.

See this link: [How can ImageView link to web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536165/how-can-imageview-link-to-web-page?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, so, i need to change all my Imageviews to ImageButton's and add Intent to every onClick method. Thanks, i'll try that :)

Comment: @dzim You don't need change ImageViews to ImageButton's and you only need one onClick method. See my answer.