# How to open a URL when click on ImageView on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, imageview

[How can ImageView Link to Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536165/how-can-imageview-link-to-web-page)

I did find this link and i copied below code over into onCreate function and out of the onCreate function and it doesn't seem to be working for me. Following is my main.java file

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Go to myurl.com when clicking on logo
       ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logoId);

       img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://casidiablo.net"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

and this is how my main.xml looks like

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

so where am i doing wrong?

I also tried to add a android:onClick="openBrowser" on main.xml and I created openBrowser function and put all the code in there, out of the onCreate function and still no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: unfortunately not. still looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add         `android:clickable="true"` in `imageview` tag as

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logoId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
```

Or add this `img.setClickable(true);` in `OnCreate` function

Comment: just tried that but it didn't work even though clickable tag made sense. Is the function in right place within onCreate function?

Comment: I think the solution is correct because when i tried that on a different project your solution has worked. However on our project where were are doing production, I am making changes to activity_main.xml file, on preview on Android Studio I am seeing the changes but when I run the app on Android VM, they are not shown there. Now looking into that trying to see what is going on.

Comment: @fcukinyahoo Delete existing project app  from Android VM and  try to clear/delete "bin","gen" folder from your project.