# case/switch statement

Tags: java, android

i need some help with switch/case statement syntax
im trying to use onClick to have different buttons do different things
i have the first one working
it just uses an intent to start a new activity.
for the next button, i want it to open a specific url
looks like this so far

```
public void onClick(View v) { 
   switch (v.getId()) { 
   case R.id.about_button: 
   Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class); 
   startActivity(i); 
   case R.id.engadget_button: 
   Intent a = new Intent(this, )
```

how do i get the engadget_button to open engadget.com?

Is it just something like this:

```
case R.id.engadget_button:
String url ="http://www.engadget.com/";
Intent a = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
a.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(a);
break;
```

??

Comment: This question has nothing to do with switch/case, but everything to do with how to open a web browser in Android. You might want to edit it to reflect this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505788/how-to-open-default-browser)

Comment: Your about_button case is missing its `break`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.androidsoftwaredeveloper.com/2009/04/15/how-to-open-a-url-from-code/